# Best practice for automatic deployment

Tags: git, web

I have multiple repositories on BitBucket.org. I want to run a `git pull` on my production server everytime a run a git push on my local machine. I have been looking around for the best solution but there seem a lot of different solutions for this.

Some say webhooks, but they seem a bit insecure to me. Ofcourse you could apply security through obscurity, but I'm not sure if this is really secure enough for a production server.

I could also set up a git hook and push to a other remote. But I want to always push to origin and not only to the production server.

So my question is, what is really the best practice for auto-deployment, 
without having to SSH into my production server and pull changes everytime I push something to the origin?

Comment: Have you considered setting up a continuous build/integration system, such as Jenkins, TeamCity or similar? To be honest, "push directly to production" sounds awfully similar to "it builds, ship it".

Comment: _"I want to run a git pull on my production server everytime a run a git push on my local machine."_ + _"(..)seem a bit insecure to me"_ + _"But I want to always push to origin and not only to the production server"_ = why don't you just set a **scheduled task** on the production server that will do a `git pull` from your `origin`, let's say, once every minute? If nothing new posted, it will be a very quick and almost no-op. If anything new is posted, you will get it on prod in up to 60 seconds after pushing out. That's pretty much as secure as if you'd do it by hand after push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CI tool alongside with git - you can achieve your goal with pure git hooks, but I would strongly advise against. Here is how you setup a generic workflow using SemaphoreCI: https://semaphoreci.com/docs/generic-deployment.html - they have very nice and beginner-friendly documentation, you should go through if you have questions about the CI topic.

If you have private repositories (I guess you are since you are using bb) and you are on a budget, you can use http://codeship.com or https://circleci.com/ since they have a free tier.

Another thing you can do if you are willing to leave bitbucket is to use https://gitlab.com/, and then you will have your CI integrated with unlimited builds with no costs. The only downside is their UI is a bit overcomplicated so that some things can be confusing at first but their feature set is a killer.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm going to take a look at those CI's you mentioned. And yes, you are completely right, I need the repositories to be private. I have not yet tried Gitlab, I chose for Bitbucket as I'm hearing more positive things about them than Gitlab. But I will give Gitlab a go too!